# trying to make sure a string buffer is a reasonable persons name

Tags: c

This is one of those tasks where I wonder why there isn't a basic C99 function
somewhere called namesafe( char *in) that just does the job. This would be nice
in a perfect world and totally useless for names written in UTF-8 Hebrew or 
perhaps Greek.  However suppose I was stuck with seven bit ascii then I tried
the following :

```
  /* We may even go so far as to ensure that any apostrophe, or hyphen
   * or period may only appear as single entities and not as two or three
   * in a row.  This does not, however, protect us from total non-sense
   * such as D'Archy Mc'Clo.u. d.
   *
   * walk the first_name string and throw away everything that is 
   * not in the range A-Z or a-z, with the exception of space char which
   * we keep. Also a single hyphen is allowed. 
   * 
   * This all seems smart but we are not protected from stupidity such
   * As a name with spaces and dashes or hypens intermixed with letters
   * or from the artist formally known as 'Prince'. 
   */
    char buffer[256];
    j = 0;
    for ( k=0; k<strlen(first_name); k++ ) {

        /* Accept anything in the a - z letters */
        if ( ( first_name[k] >= 'a' ) && ( first_name[k] <= 'z' ) )
            buffer[j++] = first_name[k];

        /* Accept anything in the A - Z letters */
        if ( ( first_name[k] >= 'A' ) && ( first_name[k] <= 'Z' ) )
            buffer[j++] = first_name[k];

        /* reduce double dashes or hyphens to a single hyphen */
        while (( first_name[k] == '-' ) && ( first_name[k+1] == '-' ))
            k++;
        if ( first_name[k] == '-' )  /* do I need this ? */
            buffer[j++] = first_name[k];

        /* reduce double spaces to a single space */
        while (( first_name[k] == ' ' ) && ( first_name[k+1] == ' ' ))
            k++;
        if ( first_name[k] == ' ' )   /* do I also need this ? */
            buffer[j++] = first_name[k];

    }
    /* we may still yet have terminating spaces or hyphens on buffer */
    while ( ( j > 1 ) && (( buffer[j-1] == ' ' ) || ( buffer[j-1] == '-' )) )
        j--;
    buffer[j] = '\0';

    /* Accept this new cleaner First Name */
    strcpy ( first_name, buffer );
```

Seems to work well enough so long as the input name buffer is not more than 255
chars in length.  However on first pass I wonder how to get rid of leading spaces
and noise like mixtures of dashes and hyphens and possibly apostrophes ?

So the question is ... how to make this better and also, do I need those lines
where I ask if ( first_name[k] == '-' ) and the same for a space? I just did
a walk over the buffer looking for duplicates and SHOULD land on a hyphen
or single space.  Right?

Comment: See http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: Actually I do not rule out a dash in the name.  I accept a single dash just fine.  Double dashes get reduced to a single dash.  Double spaces get reduced to a single space.  I think I jumped on a land mine here really ...

Comment: @Jason: I don't have a middle name, either, so I've invented a letter, as other prominent people do (Jane K. Rowling, Homer J. Simpson, George R.R. Martin), and now I have a shiny meaningless _R._ where ever I need a middle name.

Comment: I once encountered the *story* of someone whose first name **is** "La-a". It's pronounced Ladasha. The poor girl has so much trouble getting systems (and people!) to accept that that **is** her name. To be clear, I don't know if this story is true but that doesn't matter. The world is an incredibly diverse place; a name is whatever someone thinks that their name is. Don't make your poor users suffer by making unreasonable assumptions about what a name can and can not be. In particular, you can't even rule out `-` in a first name. It's not "noise" as you say, it's part of her name!

Comment: Additionally, my wife does not have a middle name because she comes from a country where there are none. She wanted to take her old last name as her middle name when got married (note, not a hyphenated last name, or a two-word last name, but a first, middle and last name). No dice, because the systems in her home country could *not* accept a middle name, she could not make her name on her passport match what she wanted.

Comment: Mark Ransom posted the best thing I have seen in ages. That article says " I have never seen a computer system which handles names properly and doubt one exists, anywhere." so really I should just go back to the people I work with and say ... the artist formally known as Prince is an acceptable name .. so stick that in the database.

Comment: @rodrigo: She *can't* legally do that. The systems in her country absolutely will not accept a middle name. Her name can not be what *she* wants it to be because of order imposed on names by government computer systems. She *tried* to get it changed, but at the end of the day the bureaucracy won.

Comment: @Jason: Oh! I haven't tried to change my official name. That's just my _artistic name_, and only in forms where a middle name is required. Should I try to change it this way, I'm afraid I would find similar problems...

Comment: And then you'll get some celebrity who wants to name their kid '42' or something...

Comment: someone actually gave this thing a negative one ... must be small little people out there that can't see this is a valid and interesting problem.

Comment: @Jason: Our ob/gyn had himself delivered a baby named "N-a", pronounced "en-dash-ah", so I can believe it.

Comment: @paullanken I'm not the downvoter, but I will point out that this question basically amounts to us trying to guess exactly what is your notion of a proper name. If you want to make it objective, you should post a clear and detailed spec of what you consider a name to be and ask how to most efficiently validate/transform input to meet that spec.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at it purely as an abstract programming problem of how to clean up your code, you could use `isalpha()` to ensure that your buffer contains only letters of the alphabet, single hyphens, and single spaces:

```
for (k = 0; k < strlen(first_name); k++) {

   if (isalpha (first_name[k])
       buffer [j++] = first_name[k++];

   else if (( first_name[k] == '-' ) && (isalpha (first_name [k+1])))
       buffer [j++] = first_name[k++];

   else if (( first_name[k] == ' ' ) && (isalpha (first_name [k+1])))
       buffer [j++] = first_name[k++];

   else
       k++;
}
```

This is just a draft. I haven't actually tried this, so no guarantees. Also, this won't handle cases where a name like "John - Paul" is written out with a space before and after the hyphen properly; you'll end up with a single space instead of a single hyphen. You can probably put in a couple of additional "else" clauses if you want to catch such edge cases.

That said, as a concrete real-world solution, I agree that it would be better to just treat names exactly as inputted. I have an unusual name myself and I get rather tired of having to explain to people that yes, this really is my name, and no, you cannot change it to suit your ideas of acceptable names.